# Physics won't set to the bounds of an iPhone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to set the bounds of the iPhone screen to be like walls.

I have tried this approach and it didn't work

```
  physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

I have also tried this and this did not work

```
let physicsFrame = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody = physicsFrame
```

I have also set the project to only portrait mode. Do I have to set it programatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set bounds to Scene physics body to bounce properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048916/how-to-set-bounds-to-scene-physics-body-to-bounce-properly)